# How to scale animate a layout diagonally from bottom to top in android?

Tags: android, animation, scaleanimation

I am trying to use `Scale Animation` on a `RelativeLayout`. I want to scale the image from the left corner to the right corner i.e diagonally(left to right) from bottom to top. I have used the following line of code but I am not getting the desired outcome.  And can anyone explain me in simple words what does  pivotx and pivoty do?

```
ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 1, 0);
```

Comment: do this in xml file n load that animation in code..

Answer (score 10):

I am using the following to animate `ImageView` from left bottom to right top. i.e. diagonally from bottom to top.

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(
             0f, 1f, 
             0f, 1f,
             Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
             Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF , 1);
scaleAnim.setDuration(10000);
scaleAnim.setRepeatCount(0);
scaleAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
scaleAnim.setFillAfter(true);
scaleAnim.setFillBefore(true);
scaleAnim.setFillEnabled(true);

img.startAnimation(scaleAnim);
```

You would need to give pivot and its value carefully.

In this case I will give a brief idea of how that works with documentation explanation:

> fromX: Horizontal scaling factor to apply at the start of the
>   animation
>
> toX: Horizontal scaling factor to apply at the end of the animation
>
> fromY: Vertical scaling factor to apply at the start of the animation
>
> toY: Vertical scaling factor to apply at the end of the animation

We need to start the animation from small dot and want to scale it to its size. So `fromX` and `fromY` are taken as 0f, and `toX` and `toY` are 1f.

> pivotXType: Specifies how pivotXValue should be interpreted. One of
>   Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or
>   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
>
> pivotXValue: The X coordinate of the point about which the object is
>   being scaled, specified as an absolute number where 0 is the left
>   edge. (This point remains fixed while the object changes size.) This
>   value can either be an absolute number if pivotXType is ABSOLUTE, or a
>   percentage (where 1.0 is 100%) otherwise.

We want the left bottom edge of `ImageView` to be there throughout animation. So we use pivotXType - `ABSOLUTE`. and 0 will be the point which should be there throughout animation.

> pivotYType: Specifies how pivotYValue should be interpreted. One of
>   Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or
>   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.
>
> pivotYValue: The Y coordinate of the point about which the object is
>   being scaled, specified as an absolute number where 0 is the top edge.
>   (This point remains fixed while the object changes size.) This value
>   can either be an absolute number if pivotYType is ABSOLUTE, or a
>   percentage (where 1.0 is 100%) otherwise.

The ImageView Y axis needs to be animated relative to its current position. So pivotYType is `RELATIVE_TO_SELF` and 1 is its bottom corner. so the bottom won't be moved up along with scaling.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this, place this in your anim folder and set that to your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <scale android:fromXScale="0.0" android:fromYScale="1.0"
          android:toXScale="1.0" android:toYScale="0.0" 
          android:duration="700" android:fillBefore="false" />

</set>
```

place this in java code:

```
Animation logoMoveAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.logoanimation); 
layout.startAnimation(logoMoveAnimation);
```